# Group-by fails when adding a linked data source to a query

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have the following code which builds a query on the Req Trans table to show me consolidated quantities by Item/Site;

```
query = new Query();
dsReqTrans = query.addDataSource(tablenum(ReqTrans));

dsReqTrans.addRange(fieldnum(ReqTrans, ReqPlanId)).value(_reqPlanId);
dsReqTrans.addRange(fieldnum(ReqTrans, RefType)).value(enum2str(_reqRefType));

dsReqTrans.addGroupByField(fieldnum(ReqTrans, ItemId));
dsReqTrans.addSelectionField(fieldnum(ReqTrans, Qty),  SelectionField::Sum);

dsInventDim = dsReqTrans.addDataSource(tablenum(InventDim));
dsInventDim.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);
dsInventDim.relations(false);
dsInventDim.addLink(fieldnum(ReqTrans, CovInventDimId), fieldnum(InventDim, InventDimId));

dsInventDim.addGroupByField(fieldnum(InventDim, InventSizeId));
dsInventDim.addGroupByField(fieldnum(InventDim, InventSiteId));

rangeInventSiteId = dsInventDim.addRange(fieldnum(InventDim, InventSiteId));
rangeInventSiteId.value(_parmSiteId);
```

This works very well. I get the sum of the qty column by item/site.

However, if I want to also add a range on ItemGroupId. For this i need to link to the InventTable like so;

```
dsInventTable = dsReqTrans.addDataSource(tablenum(InventTable));
dsInventTable.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);
dsInventTable.relations(false);
dsInventTable.addLink(fieldnum(ReqTrans, ItemId), fieldnum(InventTable, ItemId));

dsInventTable.addRange(fieldnum(InventTable, ItemGroupId)).value(_parmItemGroupId);
```

When I add this data source, the link to InventDim is broken. I get a sum of all item qty for all sites grouped by item only, rather than grouped per item/site.

Why could this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you cannot have two inner joins to the same data source (you can, but it will not work).

If using AX 2012 you can add the `InventTable` data source to the `InventDim` instead:

```
dsInventTable = dsInventDim.addDataSource(tablenum(InventTable));
dsInventTable.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
dsInventTable.relations(false);
// OBS 3 arguments next:
dsInventTable.addLink(fieldnum(ReqTrans, ItemId), fieldnum(InventTable, ItemId), dsReqTrans.name()); 
dsInventTable.addRange(fieldnum(InventTable, ItemGroupId)).value(_parmItemGroupId);
```

In earlier versions you put `InventTable` first (remember to group by one field from `InventTable`):

```
query = new Query(); 
dsInventTable = dsReqTrans.addDataSource(tablenum(InventTable)); 
dsInventTable.addGroupByField(fieldnum(InventTable, ItemId)); // You have to group/sum something
dsReqTrans = dsInventTable.addDataSource(tablenum(ReqTrans)); 
dsReqTrans.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin); 
dsReqTrans.relations(false); 
dsReqTrans.addLink(fieldnum(InventTable, ItemId).fieldnum(ReqTrans, ItemId));
...
```

Comment: I never knew that. I always thought of it as T-SQL but obviously has some differences

Comment: Actually, you can have 2 (or more) inner joins to the same data source. You need to set the fetch mode for the joined data sources to QueryFetchMode:One2One. The default is One2Many (1:n) which appears to fail -- but on subsequent reads you would get the additional joined tables.